# Remove license agreement without copying all other dialogs in WIX3.5

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I know the way to remove the LicenseAgreement dialog from the sequence of the shown dialogs in WIX. But after I change Mondo or InstallDir wxs files, it comes out, that I need to include in my WIX project all other dialogs that Mondo or InstallDir use. And it's quite a big number of files.

Is there any other way to change the installation dialogs sequence conviniently? Am I missing something?

Comment: how did u remove the LicenseAgreement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. I just needed to add a new wxs AND reference to WIX UI.